# Contacts + Google: Sync 'Collected addresses'

Tags: mail.app, contacts, google

I'm using a Google mail account for work and I didn't really add any people to contacts. I just mailed people and with time Google autocompleted the addresses and added the names (I guess this is what the 'Collected addresses' label is).

Thing is, I started using a MacBook and added my Google account to sync mail, contacts and calendar. As it turns out, 'Collected addresses' nor 'Frequently contacted' get synced so I have 0 contacts and 0 autocomplete assistance when writing mails with the Mail app.

Any way around this? I know I can select all collected addresses and add the to my contacts but I would have to do this periodically as new addresses are added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple is supposed to have their own feature that detects people, but I agree that syncing Google's over would be much cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, the Mail app seems to be autocompleting with known addresses but just the most recent ones (guess since I started using it). Google has years of collected addresses.